# Vagrant - Chef provisioning

Tags: vagrant, chef-infra, provisioning, chef-solo, vagrantfile

I need help regarding chef...

-> I packaged ubuntu w/ gui

-> on vagrantfile Im running chef.. but because it's gui it doesn't run the installations (vagrant up)
help anyone?

additional infos:: gui = true

when running the vagrantile on a non gui box, you will see the installations on your terminal being performed automatically...

when vagrant up it stops here

Vagrant::Errors::VagrantError: The following SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status.
Vagrant assumes that this means the command failed!

mkdir -p /vagrant

Stdout from the command:

Stderr from the command:

sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `vagrant` user is allowed to execute sudo commands without password prompt.

Usually this can be achieved by adding this line to `/etc/sudoers`

```
vagrant ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Or just edit line with admins group (this is how it's done in official `precise64` vagrant box)

```
%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

Note that you should edit `/etc/sudoers` only with `sudo visudo` command.

P.S. This method is quick and dirty way, it's better to manage `/etc/sudoers.d/` folder and never touch `/etc/sudoers` file manually.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you vagrant user is not in the sudoers list.

Compare /etc/sudoers.d on gui and non-gui box.